# Path to excel file to convert to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, excel, path

I'm working on a project and I need to convert an Excel sheet to JSON, and after that the data converted will be displayed with jQuery Datatables on the browser.
My code is working fine but only when I have the Excel file on the same folder of the html file. How can I get the path to the excel file from other folder to use in my script?

This is my code:

```
function asyncReq(callback) {

        var url = "LICENCIAMENTOS PROJECTOS.xlsx";
        var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        oReq.open("GET", url, true);
        oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

        oReq.onload = function(e) {
            var arraybuffer = oReq.response;
            /* convert data to binary string */
            var data = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
            var arr = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
            var bstr = arr.join("");

            /* Call XLSX */
            var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {
                type: "binary"
            });

            /* DO SOMETHING WITH workbook HERE */

            var sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[22];

            /* Get worksheet */

            var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheet_name];


            /*RANGE DA TABELA*/
            //worksheet['!ref'] = "A10:AL363";
            var data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {range: 4});
            $("h4").remove();
            callback(data);
        }
        oReq.send();

    }

    asyncReq(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        $("#tabela-data").show();

        //DataTable 
        $('#tabela-data').DataTable({
            "language": {
                "lengthMenu": "Apresentar _MENU_ linhas por página",
                "search": "Pesquisar:",
                "info":    "Apresentadas _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ linhas",
                "next":       "Próximo",
                "previous":   "Anterior"
            },
            "dom": '<"pull-left"f><"pull-right"l>tip',
            "aaData": result,
            "aoColumns": [

            ....

            ]
        });

    });
```

Comment: Adjust the `url` to reflect location. We have no idea where it is relative to your page

Comment: I must have the file in a folder on my desktop.
I can declare the url with the path to the file but i get this error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/username/Desktop/Licenciamentos/LICENCIAMENTOS%20PROJECTOS.xlsx. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: Because that isn't a web path. Is this page being opened from a server - localhost or remote?

Comment: Ok, i see. Sorry if i did not explain myself better.
But is it possible to access that file ?

Comment: It's being opened from localhost.

Comment: shouldn't see the hard drive path when page is running on localhost server and shouldn't be using hard drive path in the url either

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a relative path here for `url`.

For `url = "LICENCIAMENTOS PROJECTOS.xlsx"`, the path used in `oReq.open("GET", url, true);` is `'./LICENCIAMENTOS PROJECTOS.xlsx'`.

For an application structure with spreadsheets in a folder as:

```
index.html
spreadsheets/
   LICENCIAMENTOS PROJECTOS.xlsx
```

your `url` path will be **`spreadsheets/LICENCIAMENTOS PROJECTOS.xlsx` or `./spreadsheets/LICENCIAMENTOS PROJECTOS.xlsx`**

If you want to backtrack to a folder in some other location with an application structure as:

```
app/
    index.html
spreadsheets/
   LICENCIAMENTOS PROJECTOS.xlsx
```

your `url` path will be **`../spreadsheets/LICENCIAMENTOS PROJECTOS.xlsx` or `./../spreadsheets/LICENCIAMENTOS PROJECTOS.xlsx`**

Depending on the location of the spreadsheet, you can backtrack to it.

Comment: I try to do something like this (this is the folder where i must have that file):

var url = "C:/Users/username/Desktop/Licenciamentos/LICENCIAMENTOS PROJECTOS.xlsx";

But i get this error in Chrome:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/username/Desktop/Licenciamentos/LICENCIAMENTOS%20PROJECTOS.xlsx. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: What path is localhost serving from?

Comment: I think that is C:\wamp64\www, I'm using WAMP.
I searched about this and understand that that inside the localhost I can locate the file with no problem. But can it be possible to use a file that is in other folder of my computer?
This web aplication is only to be used by computers sharing the same network.

Comment: You should consider moving the file to a folder in the location being served from for security reasons. Otherwise, `url = '/../../ Users/username/Desktop/Licenciamentos/LICENCIAMEN‌​TOS%20PROJECTOS.xlsx‌​'`

Comment: Ok i understand this security reasons, and it makes sense.
But the computers are all connected to the same network Harddrive so I was thinking that any computer could simply run the html code with the aplication. I dont really need to host the website, but the XMLHttpRequest does not make it so simple.